# escaping a value in javascript when submitting form onclick

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am sending sensitive data encrypted when the user clicks the onclick event.  This encrypted data at times contains a plus sign (`+`) When I retrieve this request variable on the server, the `+` is getting converted to a whitespace.  This causes the decryption to fail.

Example:

```
xrUxHtYpO2Yu3Z31ve+KNA==
```

gets converted to:

```
xrUxHtYpO2Yu3Z31ve KNA==
```

Is there a way escape the string so it is sent as is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is "encodeURIComponent()":

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent("nasty string");
```

You shouldn't need any code at all on the server side; URL encoding will almost certainly be implicitly un-done by your web framework. (Edit - ah, if you're using some Java/JSP web framework, then you definitely don't have to do anything fancy on the server side.)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `+` with `%2B`. That came from [HTML URL Encoding Reference at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp). Hope this helps!

Comment: I would have done that but I think that is a hack. what if later on there are other characters I am not aware of. I wanted to take the escape route

Comment: @Omnipresent - that is true, you'd have to know which characters needed escaped beforehand. But if the `+` was your only problem then you'd be set! :)

Comment: @Pointy ahh..yeah. that's why during my pre-SO-google-search I didn't find `escapeURIComponent()` method anywhere on w3schools

Comment: `+` was the only one I found. there are 5 million records in total. :)